# Incompatible types when using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

First: this is my first time using GSON.

Trying to parse some JSON, I got "incompatible types"...

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
PlayerData data = gson.fromJson(response, PlayerData.class); // Incompatible types...
```

`PlayerData` is an inner class:

```
class PlayerData {
    public Point position;
    public String mapname;
    public int level;

    public PlayerData() {}
}
```

What causes it? In the GSON docs there is clearly a method `public <T> T fromJson(String json,
                      Class<T> classOfT)
           throws JsonSyntaxException` and I am doing at (AFAIK) just like Google in it's GSON User Guide.

**Edit:**
XCode was doing something strange, when I tried to compile this with `Terminal` everything worked, except for my request to the server, what resulted in a couple of NPE's, because `response` remained empty. Thanks to maaartinus I learned that there *shouldn't* be an compiler error so I tried to compile it without XCode.

Comment: Whats value of response?

Comment: That doesn't matter, as it's a compiler error. Response is a string that I get from my server at runtime. But because the error occurs before th application got run the value is never actually obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it compiles, but I had to replace `GSON` by `Gson`. Either you were sloppy when writing this question or you're using some "GSON" I've never heard about.

Is your `response` a `String`???

Once you get it running, you'll need the answer by Vrushank Desai.

Comment: Yes, response is a String, but AFAIK this is a compiler error, so the value of response is never retrieved from the question.

Comment: But that doesn't change the type of course... Wrote that comment too early in the morning.

Comment: You were right! It is an XCode bug, I guess. When I compile this via `Terminal` it compiles, but gives me a couple of NullPointerExceptions. Apparently my request to the server doesn't work, because `response` remains emtpy.

Answer (score 3):

Try making your inner class `static` or you'll need a custom `InstanceCreator` for it as stated in the [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Nested-Classes-including-Inner-Classes-)

> Gson can not automatically deserialize the pure inner classes since
>   their no-args constructor also need a reference to the containing
>   Object which is not available at the time of deserialization. You can
>   address this problem by either making the inner class static or by
>   providing a custom InstanceCreator for it.

Comment: This doesn't work, it still says `incompatible types`. I wish XCode 2.5 was a little more informative.

Comment: That's a funny tool (or you can't use it). Normally, such a problem should take a couple of seconds, quite often pressing `ctrl-1` in eclipse solves it.